# True 3d illusion using purely css3

Tags: css

In [this demo](http://www.zachleat.com/bigtext/demo/) you can rotate the x axis to give a 3d illusion. Trying the rotatex() css option only seems provide part of the illusion.

In the top section of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNaYB.png) you can see the 3d illusion from the 'bigtext' demo. The text is not only rotated on the x angle but the edges of the text are slightly angled in towards each other making for a much better illusion.

What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/3d-transform-functions.html). I needed to add the perspective to the parent div.

Comment: It will be better if you post the relevant portion of the link here and create a demo.